# Monitoring Worksheet change from Addin

Tags: excel, vba, office-addins

I've seen examples that allow worksheet change to be monitored from an addin, however a replica of their code doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong? The following is in ThisWorkbook of my xlam addin:

```
Private WithEvents mApp As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set mApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub mApp_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "Sheet change detected"
End Sub
```

mApp_SheetChange is never triggered

Comment: Please ignore this question. I don't seem to have option to delete it.

Reason to ignore - I had SheetChange mixed up with SheetActivate so wasn't seeing behaviour I expected.

Comment: If anyone has guidance on how to delete a question, please let me know - I don't seem to have the option